Derivation of transition density for AR/ARMA
Suppose $X_{t}$ is given by the following AR(1) model:
$$X_{t} = \alpha +\beta X_{t-1} + \epsilon_{t}.$$
As the mean of $X_{t}$ is given by $\mu = \frac{\alpha}{1-\beta}$, we can rewrite the AR(1) process as:
$$X_{t} = \mu + (X_{t-1}-\mu)\beta+ \epsilon_{t}.$$
Recursively, we can obtain
$$X_{t} = \mu + (X_{t-p}-\mu)\beta^{p}+\beta^{p-1}\epsilon_{t-(p-1)}+...\beta \epsilon_{t-1}+\epsilon_{t}.$$
Therefore, $E[X_{t}|X_{t-p}=x_{t-p}] = \mu + (x_{t-p}-\mu)\beta^{p}$.
Now, I want to derive conditional transition density for any $\tau>0$.
$$E[X_{t+\tau}|X_{t}=x_{t}]=\mu + (x_{t}-\mu)\beta^{\tau}$$
When $\tau = 1$, then I assume that $X_{t+1}$ has a normal distribution with $E[X_{t+1}|X_{t}=x_{t}]=\mu + (x_{t}-\mu)\beta$. What distribution has $X_{t+\tau}$, where $\tau >1$? Is this still normal?
When $\tau \to \infty$, then $E[X_{t+1}|X_{t}=x_{t}]=\mu$ (given that $|\beta|<1$). In limit, what is the distribution?
Is there any extension for the ARMA? Also, I assume that this derivations already have been done in econometrics textbooks. If you know any reference, please provide.

No, your reasoning is not correct. You should get $E[X_{t+\tau}|X_{t}]\rightarrow E[X_{t+\tau}]=\mu$ as $\tau\rightarrow\infty$. Try recursive substitution using the first equation. And indeed, you can find the relevant result in any decent time series textbook.

This comment is not important but it's best to use $Y_t$ for the response because $X_t$ is usually used a predictor so it can make things confusing.

Sane: What you wrote ( you mean $\beta$ not $\theta$), $\frac{\mu}{1-\beta}$, is what is often termed the lag multiplier in econometrics. It is the overall effect on $X_{t+1}$ due to a unit impulse response, $\epsilon_{t+1} = 1$. But that effect dies out over time so it's not the new mean of the response. It's the total ( i.e. cumulative ) effect of the impulse ( i.e: $\epsilon_{t+1}$) on $X_{t+1}$ over all periods in the future.. But the effect at each time $(t+i) ~\forall i$ dissipates over time and eventually goes away totally so the long term mean of the process, $\mu$ , doesn't change.

This is where one of those political science papers I referred to does come in somewhat handy. The model you wrote is an AR(1) rather than an ADL(1,1) but the "long term effects" section in the paper at the link explains in more detail what I was trying to convey above. The fact that there are $Y's$ and $X's$ at the linked paper doesn't matter. The $Y's$ in that paper are essentially your X$ so you have an  ADL(1,0). So, not really different.  https://public.websites.umich.edu/~franzese/DeBoefKeele.2008.TakingTimeSeriously.pdf

I should mention that my comment just re-inforces what Richard Hardy said. So nothing new there except an explanation of what that expression is.

I think I know where is my mistake. Will revise the question.

@RichardHardy I modified the question.

@mlofton Corrected the question, I assume.

Sane: Assuming you want the transition density for $\tau$ steps out,   it will  be just the same as one step density ( normal ) with the same expectation but the variance will become $\tau \sigma^2$ because the variances are additive due to independence. Does that make sense ?

in the book below, page 84 the author says that: " In the previous section, on estimation, we discussed the notion that transition densities tend to appear locally normal as the time between successive observations decreases. ... but when we're assessing the merit of a trade over a horizon of more than, say, one week, we can rely less on the local normality of our transition densities." https://www.wiley.com/en-us/Fixed+Income+Relative+Value+Analysis+%2B+Website%3A+A+Practitioner%27s+Guide+to+the+Theory%2C+Tools%2C+and+Trades%2C+2nd+Edition-p-9781394189083

This causes confusion to me. If time horizon is relatively large can we still assume that the density function is normal? The book that I have mentioned, assumes no ... but I am not sure.

Sane: I'm not sure  but it says that "transition densities tend to appear locally normal as the time between successive observations decreases". Assuming that the term "successive observations" in above can be replaced with "successive transitions", then it could possibly make sense to me. With very small time changes, the transitions could possibly be approximated by a brownian motion ( which is also normal with variance the same order as the time change ) but, then, as the time changes get longer, the brownian motion property ( i.e. the normal property ) gets washed away.

Sane: I also made a mistake when deriving the variance for the transition density. It should be $\sum_{i=0}^{i=\tau-1} \beta^{i} \sigma^2 = \frac{\beta^{\tau} \sigma^2}{1-\beta}$. Basically, the variances add but the error terms get smoothed by $\beta$ at each step so that has to be accounted for when calculating the variance. It's in the comment where I said "Does that make sense". It better not because it's wrong !!!! LOL. This comment is the fix to that.
