Are stationary processes non-predictable, and non-stationary ones predictable?
I am reading A canonical analysis of multiple time series by Box and Tiao (1977). In the abstract of the paper, the authors mention:

The least predictable components are often nearly white noise which can reflect stable contemporaneous relationships among the original variables. The most predictable can be nearly nonstationary representing the dynamic growth characteristic of the series.

Is this intuitive? Is white noise non-predictable and non-stationary ones predictable?

Somewhat related: the notion of unpredictability is discussed here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/620271/definition-of-unpredictable

I stand by my comment in the linked thread. Certainly white noise is predictable: a calibrated density prediction for N(0,1) data is N(0,1). It is certainly better than an N(0,5) or N(1,1) prediction.

Stephan Kolassa: I agree with you that it's "predictable" but "predictability" usually means using another variable ( or lagged variable ) to predict rather than using the density.  But this is going around in circles because the definition of predictability is the link that Richard pointed to above !!!!!!!

Here is a possible angle on this (cf. Brockwell/Davis, p40):
The best linear predictor $l(Y_{T})=aY_{T}+b$ for a stationary time series $Y_{T+h}$ based on $Y_{T}$ minimizes $E[Y_{T+h}-aY_T-b]^2$ and is given by, for $\gamma_h$ and $\rho_h$ the $h$-order autocovariance/autocorrelation,
$$
  l(Y_T)=\mu+\rho_h(Y_{T}-\mu)
$$
with MSE
$$
  E[Y_{T+h}-l(Y_{T})]^2=\gamma_0(1-\rho_h^2).
$$
BD then go on to write:

This calculation shows that [...] prediction of $X_{n+h}$ in terms of
$X_n$ is more accurate as $|\rho_h|$ becomes closer to 1, and in the
limit as $\rho_h → \pm1$ [...] the corresponding mean squared error approaches 0.

Here, I am not so sure what to make of this: consider an AR(1) process with coefficient $\rho$ and error variance 1, so that $\gamma_0=1/(1-\rho^2)$ and $\rho_h=\rho^h$.
Then
$$
MSE=\frac{1-\rho^{2h}}{1-\rho^2}
$$
Here, $\rho_h\to1$ iff $\rho\to1$. By l'Hopital's rule this tends to
$$
\lim_{\rho\to1}MSE=h,
$$
which, intuitively to me, is also the MSE of an $h$-step ahead forecast of a random walk. In particular, as the variance of the process is also affected by changes in the persistence of the process, this result suggests  that the MSE does not converge to zero and also, regarding the OP's question, that it would not be true that persistent processes are more predictable.
(An evaluation of
h <- 1:20
rho <- seq(.99, .999, by=.001)
MSE.AR <- (1-outer(rho, 2*h, "^"))/(1-rho^2)
MSE.RW <- h

matplot(h, t(MSE.AR), type="l", lwd=1)
lines(h, MSE.RW, lwd=5, lty=1, col="black")

reveals that the MSE according to this result increases in the persistence of the process.)
I am reluctant to claim, though, that BD make a mistake. Is anything wrong with my example?
UPDATE: I posted a slightly extended version of the points raised here as a separate question under Brockwell/Davis seem to say more persistence implies better predictability---do I have a counterexample?

I have checked the book. This is true when time series is stationary and Gaussian.

Stationary you are right, I added that. For this to be the best linear predictor, we do not need Gaussianity though, but under Gaussianity it would also be the best predictor.

I one more time revisited the reference that you mentioned. In that book, the author says: " .. the conditional distribution of $X_{n+h}$ given that $X_n = x_n$ is normal with $\mu+\rho(h)(x_n - \mu)$ ... and in the limit as $\rho(h) \to \pm 1$ the best predictor approaches $\mu \pm (X_n-\mu).$" The latter is just $X_{n}$ when correlation is approaching to 1. Should not approach to $\mu$ instead? See derivation here in the question: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/645891/derivation-of-transition-density-for-ar-arma?noredirect=1#comment1209152_645891

As to your first question, I would kindly ask you to read the entire page: "In the preceding calculation the assumption of joint normality of $X_{n+h}$ and $X_n$
played a crucial role. [...] However, if [...] we look for the best linear predictor,
[...], then our problem becomes that of finding $a$ and $b$ to minimize $E(X_{n+h} −aX_n −b)^2$ . [...]

As to the second, no: the best forecast for a random walk ($\rho_h=1$) is just the current value, and this is what the forecast for a stationary process tends to as $\rho_h\to1$. I believe you are maybe confusing this with the long-run forecast for a stationary process, i.e. as $h\to\infty$. For a stationary process, $\rho_h\to0$ as $h\to\infty$, and thus the long-run forecast indeed becomes $\mu$.

(To Q1 again, recall that under Gaussianity, the conditional expectation is linear, so that best predictor and best linear predictor coincide.)

Thank you, was my mistake ... i meant $h \to \infty$.

So what is your perspective from more general perspective? Are stationary processes more predictable than non-stationary ones? I assume that non-stationary processes can still be predicted. One method is Holt-Winter's filter which captures non-stationary behavior of the series,

Actually, upon some further thought I am not so sure anymore about part of what BD write. I will get back to this asap.

Take your time, thank you!

I posted my update - which raises more questions rather than answers, though... @stephankolassa ?

Sane: I don't know if they are more predictable ( I haven't had time to go through carefully what Christoph Hank showed )  but if you are concerned  about modelling non-stationarity, then the kalman filter is probably something you should look at. Note that Holt-Winters can be written as a state space model so it can also be estimated using the Kalman filter. For a discussion of the relation between state space and exponential smoothing ( HW is still an exponential smoothing model )  in general, see Hyndman's useR book "Forecasting with Exponential Smoothing".

Now that @RobHyndman is cited here I would like to try and get his view, too :-)

Sane: Christoph's comment above had me thinking  in regards to my original recommendation of what to read. A word of caution to be sure to understand the more "standard" kalman filter of Harvey, Koopman etc first because the exponential smoothing connection ( Rob Hyndman's useR book ) only holds in something called the "innovations version" of the KF. So, it's best to understand the regular KF first before you would move to the innovations version.

Harvey's blue book or the Koopman and Durbin text is best for the standard KF.  Kailath's original papers and then the useR book by Hyndman, in that order, is my recommendation for the innovations version. To some degree,  it all really depends on the level of detail you want to go into.

Christoph: Here is my take on what you did and it's correctness. If $\rho_h = 1)$ then the best linear predictor, $l(Y_T) = Y_T$. So, in that case, the best linear predictor is the last value in the series. Now, consider whatever   the dynamics of $Y$ are between $T+1$ to $T+ h$  for very large values of $h$. These dynamics should dissipate so that the true process itself returns to its original-equilibrium value of $Y_T$. So, simply speaking, if one assumes that  $lim_{h\to\infty}  E(Y_{T+h}) \rightarrow Y_T$, then It maybe in this sense that they are saying that the MSE becomes zero.

Also, that was a very nice example through the use of  the AR(1). Thanks. Oh, my $Y_T$ in above would probably be $\mu$ in the AR(1) so that would be the equilibrium value of the AR(1).

Thanks, that is a possibility - although I would humbly argue that this would be an unconventional view of an MSE being zero, as such long-run forecasts clearly will generally not be equal to the true value, hence $MSE\neq0$ (in my interpretation of an MSE at least...). Btw, I basically reposted my "answer" as a separate Q here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/646529/brockwell-davis-seem-to-say-more-persistence-implies-better-predictability-do

Christoph: I think, for my argument,to hold, some kind of "equilibrium" at T would need to be assumed. Then, as $\lim_{h\to\infty}$, the true process eventually returns to that equilibrium. Finally as you mentioned, one would also need a limiting definition of MSE which is not conventional.

Also, thanks for expanding the answer in the other thread. I don't have either Brockwell and Davis at my fingertips so including the pages was great.
